# Extjs Save DataStore to php Array

Tags: javascript, php, json, extjs

I am trying save a json structure from datastore to a php array but when I have 1 record to store, the json code is:

```
fones: {
  "id":"Agenda.model.ModeloFone-3",
  "numero":"44444444",
  "id_telefone":0,
  "id_cliente":2
},
```

When I have more than one record to store, the json code is:

```
fones: [{
  "id":"Agenda.model.ModeloFone-6",
  "numero":"234234",
  "id_telefone":0,
  "id_cliente":2
}, {
  "id":"Agenda.model.ModeloFone-7",
  "numero":"333333333",
  "id_telefone":0,"id_cliente":2
}, {
  "id":"Agenda.model.ModeloFone-8",
  "numero":"2222222",
  "id_telefone":0,
  "id_cliente":2
}]
```

How do I make these consistent as an array from extjs to php?

Comment: I have editted your question to try and make it more clear.  It is still missing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Stores always return an array - what you're describing must be custom behaviour.